# dlib install error: coule not build dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: dlib

I am new to this. Please bear with me and help me. I am not able to install dlib. I have installed visual code c++ etc. following is the error I am getting

`pip install dlib==19.24.2
Collecting dlib==19.24.2
Using cached dlib-19.24.2.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [97 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_ext
Building extension for Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)]
Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n6qzz25e\dlib_fbac7005ae1a4281a7c668e8208cb31d\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n6qzz25e\dlib_fbac7005ae1a4281a7c668e8208cb31d\build\lib.win32-cpython-37 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\safiu\pycharmprojects\opencv attendance\venv\scripts\python.exe -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n6qzz25e\dlib_fbac7005ae1a4281a7c668e8208cb31d\build\lib.win32-cpython-37'
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.37.32822.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.37.32822.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.37.32822/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Deprecation Warning at C:/Users/safiu/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n6qzz25e/dlib_fbac7005ae1a4281a7c668e8208cb31d/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:8 (cmake_minimum_required):
Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
CMake.

```
    Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
    CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


  -- pybind11 v2.10.0
  CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Users/safiu/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n6qzz25e/dlib_fbac7005ae1a4281a7c668e8208cb31d/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:98 (find_package):
    Policy CMP0148 is not set: The FindPythonInterp and FindPythonLibs modules
    are removed.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0148" for policy details.  Use
    the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:/Users/safiu/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n6qzz25e/dlib_fbac7005ae1a4281a7c668e8208cb31d/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:50 (find_package)
    C:/Users/safiu/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n6qzz25e/dlib_fbac7005ae1a4281a7c668e8208cb31d/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Common.cmake:180 (include)
    C:/Users/safiu/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n6qzz25e/dlib_fbac7005ae1a4281a7c668e8208cb31d/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:200 (include)
  This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

  -- Found PythonInterp: c:/users/safiu/pycharmprojects/opencv attendance/venv/scripts/python.exe (found suitable version "3.7", minimum required is "3.6")
  CMake Error at C:/Users/safiu/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n6qzz25e/dlib_fbac7005ae1a4281a7c668e8208cb31d/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:187 (message):
    Python config failure: Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    C:/Users/safiu/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n6qzz25e/dlib_fbac7005ae1a4281a7c668e8208cb31d/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Tools.cmake:50 (find_package)
    C:/Users/safiu/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n6qzz25e/dlib_fbac7005ae1a4281a7c668e8208cb31d/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/pybind11Common.cmake:180 (include)
    C:/Users/safiu/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-n6qzz25e/dlib_fbac7005ae1a4281a7c668e8208cb31d/dlib/external/pybind11/CMakeLists.txt:200 (include)


  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-n6qzz25e\dlib_fbac7005ae1a4281a7c668e8208cb31d\setup.py:125: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
    if LooseVersion(cmake_version) < '3.1.0':
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\safiu\pycharmprojects\opencv attendance\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "c:\users\safiu\pycharmprojects\opencv attendance\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "c:\users\safiu\pycharmprojects\opencv attendance\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 252, in build_wheel
      metadata_directory)
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 417, in build_wheel
      wheel_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 401, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 250, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 107, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 185, in setup
      return run_commands(dist)
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 201, in run_commands
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 364, in run
      self.run_command("build")
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 131, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 318, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 1234, in run_command
      super().run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_nyg148_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "<string>", line 130, in run
    File "<string>", line 167, in build_extension
    File "C:\Users\safiu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 328, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\safiu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n6qzz25e\\dlib_fbac7005ae1a4281a7c668e8208cb31d\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\safiu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n6qzz25e\\dlib_fbac7005ae1a4281a7c668e8208cb31d\\build\\lib.win32-cpython-37', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\safiu\\pycharmprojects\\opencv attendance\\venv\\scripts\\python.exe', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\safiu\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-n6qzz25e\\dlib_fbac7005ae1a4281a7c668e8208cb31d\\build\\lib.win32-cpython-37']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

Im using Windows 11, python version 3.7
cmake is installed via pip and also installed from msi file.
I have also installed visual studio community 2019 and Desktop develipment with c++